# Prove $ f(z) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} 2^{-j} z^{(2^j)}$ is holomophic on $D(0,1)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove that the function
\begin{align}
  f(z) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} 2^{-j} z^{(2^j)}
\end{align}
is holomorphic on $D(0,1)$ and continuous on $\bar{D}(0,1)$. 
and prove that if $w$ is a $(2^N)^{\textrm{th}}$ root of unity, then $\lim_{r\rightarrow 1^-} |f'(rw)| = + \infty$.

---

First i see that $f(z)$ is holomorphic, by directly differentiation with $\bar{z}$, but i have no clue for remaining things.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe, actually this is a exercise 3.21 for Robert E Green, Steven G.Krantz,Function theory of one complex varialbe,3rd edition. My guess of this function is if we differentiate this function with respect to $z$, then it produces $f'(z) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} z^{2^j-1}$.

Comment: Do you see why it is continuous on the closed disk?

Comment: @AD, i want to try ratio test or something but i am not sure about the power series for $z^{2^j}$. If i consider this as $x^j$ then $j$ should run as $1,2,4, 8, \cdots.. $ Then i am confused the same logic applies for this case.

Comment: To complete your idea with the derivative you might consider a block summation.

Comment: The sum $\sum 2^{-j}$ converges hence $f$ converges on $\bar{D}$. How can we assure continuity?